# range class is not working properly

Tags: python-3.x

Below I have mentioned my data, I am trying to use range class (19-25) for the output but somehow I am not understanding it. 
 - List item
   I want to have the results like this  if the output is less than 19
   then say " you are skinny as rail" if the output is between 19-25
   then say "you are fit as a butcher's dog" if the output is more than
   25 then say "you are as plum as a partridge"

here is my output data

```
a=float(input('what is your weight(kg)'))
b=float(input('what is your height(cm)'))
operations=[(a)/(b*b/100)*100]

output=operations
print("Your BMI is", output, "you are skinny as a rail.")
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49967166/edit) to [format it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Formatting is extremely important for Python code where indentation is significant.

Comment: Why does your code promote body shaming? :/

Comment: Also note that `range` is not a function, it's [*a class*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range).

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting. I am new to stackover flow that's why I didn't understand how to format it nicely.

Comment: Now when it's better formatted it's easier to see. And the code you show is *still* not properly formatted or indented, nor is it syntactically correct. And that's not how you use the `range` class.

Comment: could you kindly help me to write the code. I am trying to understand it but somehow it's not working

Comment: You are asking how to use range, but you edited the only line containing it out of your post?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your BMI formula but the correct formula in Metric is

```
BMI = Weight / (Height)^2
```

I'm using that in my example but you're free to change it to your liking.  There's also no need to convert the operation into a list.  Your code will not work if someone decides to enter letters instead of numbers so it's a good idea to verify that.

```
>>> def bmi ():
...     try:
...         weight = float (input ('Weight in Kgs: '))
...         height = float (input ('Height in Meters: '))
...         bmi = weight / (height * height)
...         if bmi < 19:
...             print ('Your BMI: %.2f.  You\'re skinny.' % bmi)
...         elif 19 <= bmi <= 25:
...             print ('Your BMI: %.2f.  You\'re fit.' % bmi)
...         else:
...             print ('Your BMI: %.2f.  You\'re plum.' % bmi)
...     except ValueError:
...         print ('Only numbers are accepted!')
... 
>>>
```

**Output**

```
>>> bmi ()
Weight in Kgs: 80
Height in Meters: 1.7
Your BMI: 27.68.  You're plum.

>>> bmi ()
Weight in Kgs: 60
Height in Meters: 1.7
Your BMI: 20.76.  You're fit.

>>> bmi ()
Weight in Kgs: 50
Height in Meters: 1.8
Your BMI: 15.43.  You're skinny.

>>> bmi ()
Weight in Kgs: 65
Height in Meters: a
Only numbers are accepted!
```